# Remove polylines on indoormap Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I added a polyline from current destination to the desired destination that the user wants through shortcut buttons and search.

So, when the user input a location, the line/path previously must be destroyed/erased.

I tried polyline.remove(); but nothing happen. Still, the path will generate more as the user clicks on the button.

Code:

```
a = latLng;
            PolylineOptions options = new PolylineOptions().add(updatedLatLng).width(5).color(Color.RED).geodesic(true);
            options.add(a);
            polyline.add(mGoogleMap.addPolyline(options));
            polyline.remove(a);
```

Comment: You should only paste the relevant part. Nobody is going to read that much code.

Comment: edited** sorry.